# what does "driving change" mean?

Tags: word-usage

> Brian Vellmure specializes in connecting dots, distributing
>   intelligence, and driving change at the intersection of
>   customers, technology and organizational growth.

Comment: That appears to be a bio/résumé and indeed "driving change" is a common cliché with the definition gandalf described. Did the other two verbs make sense? I might have guessed they'd be the harder of the three.

Comment: no they are hard too. I think connecting dot means connecting people and distributing intelligence is some thing like brain storming or crowd sourcing. finding solution by help of other.

Comment: My guess is *intelligence* refers to knowledge and information in a broad sense. It might specifically mean *business intelligence* though. *Connecting dots* is about making deductions and pulling disparate pieces of information together into a bigger picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the phrase is "...connecting dots, distributing intelligence, and driving change...", it would appear to be parallel structure.

Ving + noun, Ving + noun, Ving + noun

So, to drive change would mean to be the impetus or force creating change.